# Rebuilding an Oracle 19c Standby Database after plugging in a new PDB

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-19c, dataguard

I have an Oracle 19c Dataguarded physical standby DB setup running on Linux 7. The container DB had one PDB but I've now just plugged a new PDB into the primary. What do I need to do to get this new PDB replicated to the standby? Do I need to rebuild the entire standby? Many thanks.

Follow up -> It doesn't get automatically copied to the standby side as the PDB has been plugged in. I found this arcticle (for 18c) but it requires active dataguard (which is separately licensed): https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/multitenant-copying-a-pdb-in-a-data-guard-environment-18c

Does anyone know how to get a newly plugged in 19c (ASM) PDB to be replicated to the standby (without using active dataguard)?
Update: you can actually use ADG in this scenario without violating licensing agreements.

Comment: The process for this is that you need to have already copied your new PDB over to your standby site so that dataguard can replicate your `create pluggable database` command to plug the PDB in on the standby site too. Is your existing replication still working? I would fear that at the point of you plugging in the PDB to the primary, the standby would start failing as it was unable to carry out the same action. If this is the case, you may be able to copy the PDB (as it was before you plugged it in) to your standby site and restart your redo apply.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Yes that works but it turns out there’s an easier way. Creating a link to the non CDB db in the primary and then setting the STANDBY_PDB_SOURCE_FILE_DBLINK to this link in the standby (has to be open read only), will ensure all data is auto applied to the standby side when using the create pluggable command.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug in a non-CDB or a PDB from a manifest file (XML file), the PDB is created in the standby database, but the PDB is unusable because the data files are not copied to the standby database.
It is possible to re-use the data files on the standby database, but it requires a little work before the plug-in.
Or, you can create the PDB on the primary database only (STANDBYS=NONE) and the recover the PDB on the standby database.
My colleagues and I did a webinar about multitenant migration where we discussed this situation. You might take a look (forward to 1:02:09):
https://videohub.oracle.com/media/Migrate+to+the+Multitenant+Architecture/1_izx15u3d
You can also have a look at the corresponding slides here:
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=202202:2:::::P2_SUCHWORT:multitenant

Depending on which option you choose the slides have references to MOS notes for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Not required - PDB will be replicate to standby. Here is url

https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-controlling-pdb-replication-in-data-guard-environments-12c

Comment: Thanks. What if the original db and standby was encrypted and the new PDB I plug into the primary is also encrypted? Will it still get automatically replicated?

Comment: Yes it will be replicated if the wallet is OPEN & AUTO LOGIN in standby.

Comment: Many thanks. I will test this again. I upgraded an encrypted 11g DB to be a 19c non CDB then converted it and plugged it in .. the 19c was also encrypted of course. That worked but the standby did not sync and copy across the new pdb files to the standby side. I assume I needed to use the ‘ STANDBYS=ALL’ option in the create pluggable command. I will check this and update here. Thanks again.

Comment: the limitation at the start states “ The examples here assume the new PDB is created from the seed database, or from a local read-only PDB in the primary database. The read-only source PDB limitation is still true up to 19c.” So I need to change my upgraded ‘newly plugged in’ pdb info read only node, then copy it using the create pluggable cmd in the article, then drop the original db I plugged in? Is that right? Only the copy of this original will be auto built on the standby?

Comment: It doesn't work for a DB that has been plugged in I'm afraid. There's a manual process required.